# Server response not being received

Tags: socket, troubleshooting

I have a python program that sends requests via a socket connection to a local 3rd party application which in turn forwards my request to a server. The server response then makes it's way back to my socket via the 3rd party app. Everything has been working correctly for several months, with the replies from the server being instant.

On Tuesday this week all of a sudden responses from the server are seemingly not being returned occasionally. The responses are usually instant, but now on 20% of the queries there is no response for 2 minutes after which I receive an error message saying I was unable to retrieve the requested data.

I have checked with the server people and they are receiving my requests, but for some reason on a small number of them I am not receiving the response.

I tested this with a different internet connection (3g) which uses a different ISP than my DSL line. The issue appears to be resolved when using the 3g, so it looks like the issue may either lie with my DSL line or perhaps my ISP (throttling ports?)

I have no idea how to trouble shoot this. I am not a network guy, so please can any trouble shooting suggestions keep that in mind. I can test this on either linux or windows, so suggestions on either are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are using TCP socket packets, and not UDP. So that there is a retry, since most ISPs will drop packets to limit the line.

If you are using UDP the TCPIP stack will not retry sending the packet since UDP does not require an ACK. Switching to TCP will add a small overhead since an acknowledgement is required to be returned.